# Handle form submission Laravel 5

Tags: php, forms, optimization, laravel-5

I just start learning Laravel 5, and I want to know what the proper way to handle submitted forms.  I found many tutorials where we create two separate actions, where first render form, and the second actually handle form. I am came from Symfony2, where we create a single action for both, render and handle submitted form, so I want to know I need to create two separate actions because thats Laravel-way, or I can place all logic into single action, I do this like the folowing, but I dont like code what I get:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    if (Input::get('title') !== null) {
        $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title'   => 'required|unique:posts',
            'content' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($v->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }
        $post = new Post(Input::all());
        if ($post->save()) {
            return redirect('posts');
        }
    }

    return view('add_post');
}
```

So can somebody give me advice how I need do this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most important reason to create two actions is to avoid **duplicate form submissions** . You can read more about [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Another important reason is the way you keep the code cleaner. Take a look at this first change:

```
public function showForm(){
    return view('add_post');
}

public function create(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title'   => 'required|unique:posts',
            'content' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($v->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }
        $post = new Post(Input::all());
        if ($post->save()) {
            return redirect('posts');
        }
    return redirect()->route('show_form')->withMessage();
}
```

The first thing that you can notice is that `create()` function is not rendering any view, it is used to manage the creation logic (as the name itself suggests). That is OK if you plan to stay in low-profile, but what happens when you do need to add some others validations or even better, re-utilize the code in other controllers. For example, your form is a help tool to publish a comment and you want to allow only "authors-ranked" users to comment. This consideration can be manage more easily separating the code in specific actions instead making an if-if-if-if spaghetti. Again...

```
public function showForm(){
    return view('add_post');
}

public function create(PublishPostRequest $request)
{
    $post = new Post($request->all());
    $post->save()
    return redirect('posts');
}
```

Take a look on how `PublishPostRequest` request takes place in the appropriated function. Finally, in order to get the best of Laravel 5 you could create a request class to keep all the code related with validation and authorization inside it:

```
class PublishPostRequest extends Request{

    public function rules(){
        return [
            'title'   => 'required|unique:posts',
            'content' => 'required',
        ]
    }

    public function authorize(){
        $allowedToPost = \Auth::user()->isAuthor();

        // if the user is not an author he can't post
        return $allowedToPost;    

    }
}
```

One nice thing about custom request class class is that once is injected in the controller via function parameter, it runs automatically, so you do not need to worry about `$v->fails()`